# Can bluez run hooks on connect/disconnect

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

Is it possible to get bluez to run hooks when a device connects/disconnects?

I'm setting up a raspberry pi to broadcast sound from a TV to Bluetooth ear phones. I want to add a pulse audio lookback module when the earphones connect, and remove it when they disconnect.

I guess I can do this with python using the dbus interface, but writing a hook in bash would be much less work.